# wso2 EMM, not receiving e-mail on device

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I  am sending invitations using wso2 emm but those emails are actually not received on the device, what configurations do i need to change so that i could receive the mails on my devices.Any help would really be appreciated. Can anyone explain  [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/General+Server+Configurations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you Configure the email parameters? in the doc you provided? You need to configure the email settings to send out registration confirmation emails to new users and invite existing users to register their device with WSO2 EMM.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/General+Server+Configurations

Comment: Is it possible in wso2 emm that i configure two users viz one with mdm and second without mdm in a single server